# Issue with updating array data in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I am working on an invoice in which i want to update table data.

My script only updates the last row of the table. **Can this work with this foreach loop?**

Following is the script I am trying to do it with:

**HTML input fields**

```
<tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="data['+i+'][Id]" value="<?php echo $Id; ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="data['+i+'][ItemId]" value="<?php echo $item_Id; ?>" >
    <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $item; ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data['+i+'][QTY]" value="<?php echo $Quantity; ?>"</td>
    <td><input type="number" value="<?php echo $price; ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="data['+i+'][total]" value="<?php echo $total; ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    foreach($_POST['data'] as $key => $data) {
        $Id = intval($data['Id']);
        $itemId = intval($data['ItemId']);
        $QTY = intval($data['QTY']);
        $Total = intval($data['total']);

        if($itemId > 0) {
            $query = $db - > prepare("UPDATE table SET QTY = :QTY where id = :ID ");
            $query - > execute(array(':ID' => $ID, ':QTY' => $QTY));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have several variable name mismatches between your HTML and PHP snippets. Namely, `$item_Id` vs. `$itemId`, `$Quantity` vs `$QTY`, `$total` vs. `$Total`. You'd also need to provide the snippet that shows how you assign `$price` and `$item`.

Comment: What is the "i" variable inside the index of input's name?

Comment: @IvanTalanov The name of the variables would not have any impact on what is submitted, but the name of the inputs would.

Comment: @Tobia - these are multiple rows fetched from database. thats why i assigned "i" .

Comment: Can you please tell us what is the resulting html? For example:<input type="hidden" name="data[0][Id]" value="" >

Comment: @Tobia : i have checked this with `<input type="text" name="data[0][Id]" value="" >` it fetches item id and displaying it perfectly.

Comment: @geeshakm you did not answer me correctly if your problem was the "i", because I asked you to tel me the resulting html and it cannot be data[0][Id] if the problem was the data['+i+'][Id] as I supposed before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not seem to be valid syntax:

```
data['+i+']
```

PHP will consider this as a string with a fixed value, meaning your `$_POST[data]` array will only have one key, each new occurrence overwriting the previous one. In the end it will look like this:

```
$_POST[data] == array( '+i+' => array(
    'Id' => ...,
    'ItemId' => ...,
    'QTY' => ...,
    'total' => ...
));
```

You probably want to use some PHP in your code in order to properly write the `i` index:

```
<tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="data[<?php echo $i; ?>][Id]" value="<?php echo $Id; ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="data[<?php echo $i; ?>][ItemId]" value="<?php echo $item_Id; ?>" >
    <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $item; ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data[<?php echo $i; ?>][QTY]" value="<?php echo $Quantity; ?>"</td>
    <td><input type="number" value="<?php echo $price; ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="data[<?php echo $i; ?>][total]" value="<?php echo $total; ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

and increment it for each row.